# how to get data from inflated layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I newbie to Android programming so my question might be silly.
I am writing an app that user insert some delivery information for an item to be delivered. 
The user must insert up to 3 other person's contact information, incase he wont be available.

To do so the user click on a button, which inflate a new "row" into a LinearLayout(Vertical).
The row structure:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint=" phone"
        android:inputType="phone" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

</LinearLayout>
```

My question is, when the user finished to fill all data, how can i get those rows if they inserted dynamicly? do I need to iterate each row in the LinearLayout, or there is a better approch ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: "do I need to iterate each row in the LinearLayout" that would be the most dynamic solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I went with Guardanis approach.
I inflate a row each time the user click on addButton.
I attach a tag to button, indicating how many rows already added(to limit rows to 3).

BTW, since I know the hierarchy of the row, when saving the data, 
I will iterate on every row and get the values getChildAt(INDEX OF SPINNER|EDITTEXT) instead of attaching an id for each element.

Thx for all for helping me !!

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_in);
        Button addContactBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sign_in_add_contact_button);
        addContactRow();
        addContactBtn.setTag(1);        // tag value indicate how many rows already defined


        addContactBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int totalRows = (Integer)v.getTag();
                if(totalRows < 3){
                    v.setTag(totalRows+1);
                    SignInActivity.this.addContactRow();

                }
                else{
                    // insensitive the button
                }

            }
        });

    }
    private void addContactRow(){

        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.sign_in_contact_list_layout);
        ViewGroup line = (ViewGroup)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.contact_details, null);

        Spinner spinner = (Spinner)line.getChildAt(0);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.sign_in_contact_type_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        layout.addView(line);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have posted some more code, but if you want to do it like this, than you are gonna have to make ids for all layouts(three different layouts), and then yeah, basically find their children EditTexts etc.

I prefer to solve these sort of things (again if you got you right) by making all the views that could appear in your xml file, and then just making some of them invisible. You can do that by setting the attribute in your xml files.

```
android:visibility = "visible" // the view is shown
android:visibility = "invisible" // the view is hidden, but leaves blank space where 
android:visibility = "gone" // the view is litteraly gone
```

and then in your Java code, you can change their visibility on button click or whenever you want by doing this:

```
  View v;
    v.setVisible(View.GONE);// (or VISIBLE, or INVISIBLE)
```

Comment: "by making all the views that could appear in your xml file, and then just making some of them invisible" that approach will get less efficient the more data you've added to it. In his case of having a max of 3 items this may work well, but I wouldn't really consider that a dynamic solution

Comment: And i logged in, because i expected this kind of comment. :D You are right, that's why i said "these sort of things", perhaps i should have been more specific. I was indeed referring to this specific case of 3 items. Also, mu suggestion was to do it like this without complicating everything too much for a "newbie" as the guy honestly presented himself ;) I never said it was dynamic. Also, i think(as far as i know ) that its also faster, as layout inflation is a time-consuming operation ;)